# Datatables - How can i use an array as SQL where clause

Tags: php, database

I'm trying to make a Datatable that dynamically loads data based on the user's settings.

**On the server processing script**

I have an array of branches owned by the current user.

```
$branchesOwned = $db->query('SELECT branchId FROM zapp_clt_branchesowner WHERE ownerId = ?', $ownerId)->fetchAll();
```

So far so good!

i tried to create a secondary array where i would store the branchId from the 1st array :

```
$whereArray = [];

foreach ($branchesOwned as $result) {
array_push($whereArray, $result['branchId']);
}
```

now on the SSP complex i have this:

```
//$whereAll = "status = 'B Activo' AND branchID IN ('1')"; <--- WORKING
$whereAll = "status = 'B Activo' AND branchID IN {$whereArray}"; // <--- NOT WORKING


echo json_encode(
SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $whereResult = null, $whereAll)
);
```

As you can see if it write the array directly in the $whereAll it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$idsAsString = sprintf("('%s')", implode("', '", $whereArray));

$whereAll = "status = 'B Activo' AND branchID IN $idsAsString";
```